# Get a value from the string with regex

Tags: node.js, regex

I have this for example:

```
<@445288012218368010>
```

And I want to get from between <@ > symbols the value.
I tried so:

```
string.replace(/^(?:\<\@)(?:.*)(?:\>)$/gim, '');
```

But then I don't get any result. It will delete/remove the whole string.
I want only this part: 445288012218368010 (it will be dynamic, so yeah it will be not the same numbers).
Anyway it is for the discord chat bot and I know that there is other methods for check the mentioned names but I want to do that in regex because which I am trying to do can't go the common method.
So yeah how can I get the value from between those symbols?
I need this in node.js regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String#match which will return regular expression matches for the string (in this case the RegExp would be `<@(\d+)>` (the parenthesis around the `\d+` make `\d+` become its own group). This way you can use `<string>.match(/<@(\d+)>/)` to get the regular expression results and `<string>.match(/<@(\d+)>/)[1]` to get the first group of the regex (in this case the number).

Comment: The string you posted looks like a Discord user mention, you might want to use `<@!?(\d+)>` as a regex to also get the ID from nickname mentions (Discord uses slightly different mentions for this (`<@!123456789>`))

Comment: Thank you :) I will accept your answer 9 minutes later because the website doesn't allow now. :( Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You regex matches but you use a non capturing group `(?:.*)` so you get the full match and replace that with an empty string. Note that you could omit the first and the third non capturing group and use  `<@` and `>` instead.

You could match what is between the brackets using a capturing group `([^>]+)` or `(\d+)` and use replace and refer the first capturing group `$1` in the replacement.

```js
console.log("<@445288012218368010>".replace(/^<@([^>]+)>$/gim, '$1'));
```